# How to "CSS3 Gradient in Windows Phone 7"?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, css, browser, gradient

I'm working in **WP7** where my application is **based in HTML5** and I'm exporting the app through **PhoneGap framework**.

I want to know if is possible and how to generate a **CSS3 gradient** for this project (and in the process, I want to share you what I've discovered).

At the moment this is my CSS3 code:

```
body {
    background: brown;
    background-image: url(blue_to_white.jpg);
    background: linear-gradient(blue, red); /*future CSS3 browsers*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, orange); /*new webkit*/
    background-image:  -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, blue 50%, green 50%); /* IE10 */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='blue', endColorstr='purple'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='blue', endColorstr='yellow')"; /* IE8 */
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(blue, silver); /*PIE*/
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  }
```

As you can see, my code is using different techniques for the background:

- A **brown** like color base
- An image like gradient of **blue to white**
- A normal CSS3 gradient of **blue to red**
- A CSS3 gradient for webkit browsers of **blue to orange**
- A CSS3 gradient for Microsoft browsers of **blue to green**
- A DXImageTransform for IE6 & IE7 of **blue to purple**
- A DXImageTransform for IE8 of **blue to yellow**
- A pie-background using CSS3PIE of **blue to silver**

And this is my results:
[image]

As you may know, the browser for WinPhone 7.5 is IE9 Mobile, and the browser for WinPhone 7.0 is a mix between IE7 & IE8. Here into slide 16, 17 and 18 explains which CCS3 properties are implemented in IE9, IE10 and "IE9 Mobile": http://goo.gl/1Wz3s

**So, Any idea of how to generate a CSS3 gradient in Windows Phone?
or I have no choice and I must implement an image to create this gradient?**

Comment: With the HTML5 doctype and using your `-ms-filter` the gradient works fine on my WP7.5 Phone in Mobile IE. Could you post the full example html/css so we can see if something else is causing the problem?

Comment: My code is too simple, so I don't think that exist a problem in the other code.

Comment: This is all my code that I implemented: https://plus.google.com/100901511694449655005/posts/jZPUKy1p6By

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake, if I run the .html file directly in Mobile IE the gradient works fine, however, if I run it through PhoneGap the gradient doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to show the correct syntax for CSS3 Gradients in IE10+

```
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(
                 bottom,                
                 #432100 30%,               
                 #00AAAA 70%);
```

In the google code link posted by JC Del Valle, he is using a backgroung-image definition, which is not correct.

[stack overflow prevented me from inserting image]

In the screen capure at twitter link (@palermo4), I tested your styles as-is.  It appears to be working.  Something else is in conflict with your CSS3 stuff.

Comment: Thx, you're right :), but well, my target at the moment if IE9 mobile. :P

Comment: I checked and I found that the @palermo4's image is a HTML5 viewed in IE9mobile browser. I'm wrong in my question, I want to see the CCS3 gradient into a webbrowser.